# What types of words/phrases are "this" "here" & "they"?

Tags: phrases, nouns, pronouns

I'm currently doing an analytic essay on my drama coursework (fun.). I'd like to explain how the playwright never reveals the exact setting of the act, by using only phrases such as "this","here", and "they".

The exact sentence is:

> The overall effect of these two pages is that the audience becomes wary of a suspicious underlying element of the whole act, whilst maintaining the ambiguity through use of **X** such as “this”, ”here”, and "they"

Are they indirect pronouns?
Many thanks!

Comment: They are ***unreferenced*** pronouns: demonstrative, demonstrative, personal. They "maintain ambiguity" if there are no referents.

Comment: So would it be correct for me to say "through use of unreferenced pronouns..." ?

Comment: There seems to be something wrong with your sentence. It says that the audience maintains the ambiguity through use of these unreferenced deictics/pronouns—but surely the audience aren't the ones who are using them?

Comment: I would substitute "effect of these two pages is to make the audience wary..." This averts making the audience the putative subject of  "whilst...."

Comment: Ah, you're right. Oops. I'll change that now. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Try "indirect terms".

Or, as ScotM suggested, "unreferenced"

"This" and "they" are pronouns, but "here" isn't.

Comment: Isn't _unreferenced deictic_ a contradiction in terms? _Deictic manqué_?

Comment: Even I don't include 'deictics' as a word class. 'Here' is deictic (your 'here' is usually different from mine), but I'd class it as a locative/directional particle. 'They' _should_ only be used deictically, but the classic 'They say it's not as bad as they say it is' deserves preserving for posterity.